# jQuery tickboxes, Ticked / Unticked Logic

Tags: jquery

I am working on a logic for checkboxes. Where if the checkbox is unticked, It hides the created list item. An example of this is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYtXX/) I have the tick logic working, But what I'd like is the "Untick" logic to work.

I have given each li item a class, So basically looking to pair the two together to remove the list item. But just not having any luck.

Can anyone help me on extending this logic so that I show / hide the unticked li item, Otherwise I'm just left with a never ending list of items.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Use the `change` event for listening to checkboxes. If you use `click`, you ignore any state changes that come from keyboard interaction.

2) Your current "if not checked" code is creating a NEW `li` and removing that (before it's even entered the DOM) - presumably not what you meant.

I've assumed you meant to remove CURRENT `li`s that have a class equal to the `name` attribute of the changed checkbox. See updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qYtXX/9/

Comment: I see what your saying. Each li has an class that pairs to the tickboxes class. So if that class is unticked, Remove the list item that matches the untick.

Comment: @Utkanos Almost there however on your version when un-ticking the check box it removes all LI's not just the one it should

Comment: See updated Fiddle - HOWEVER, it's still going to fail because your checkbox names/`li` classes contain spaces. This will ruin everything, as HTML deems spaces in class attributes to denote several, different classes. Ensure these names/spaces contain no spaces (e.g. underscores) and all should be fine.

Comment: [myversion](http://jsfiddle.net/qYtXX/9/) take a look at that i simply replace the spaces with underscores to ensure it works

Comment: Great - mission accomplished, then.

Comment: Thanks guys! Loving the regular expression check. Because I'm working with PHP that data with spaces was coming from the DB. So I've had to do a string replace to add underscores, Then when outputting replace them with spaces. That should do the trick.

Comment: haha, all this time I was talking with @AbstractChaos I was thinking he was the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the spaces from the *name* attributes of *checkboxes*, try the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" title="100.00" class="service_check" value="8" name="Test Service Name">
```

=>

```
<input type="checkbox" title="100.00" class="service_check" value="8" name="TestServiceName">
```

```
    else if ($(this).not(":checked")) { // you can replace this line with "else {"
        var cls = $(this).attr('name') 
        $("li."+cls).remove();
        $(".hidden_service_id, .hidden_service_name, .hidden_service_cost").val("");
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qYtXX/7/)